# Error - VALIDATION_ERROR : This field required when payment_method is 'paypal'

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating android Paypal SDK in my Android app, here I have got my client id and using in my code, When I start transaction with "Pay with Paypal" then I get error message "Payment information is invalid, please correct and submit again";

Any suggestion ??

Logs :

```
03-30 16:58:50.106    1491-1771/com.example.paypaldemo.app E/paypal.sdk﹕ request failure with http statusCode:400,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
03-30 16:58:50.106    1491-1771/com.example.paypaldemo.app E/paypal.sdk﹕ request failed with server response:{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"redirect_urls","issue":"This field required when payment_method is 'paypal'"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"587f8072ed4d6"}
03-30 16:58:50.130    1491-1491/com.example.paypaldemo.app E/PayPalService﹕ VALIDATION_ERROR
```

Code :

```
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"), "USD", "hipster jeans",
        PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I have just verified PayPal payments using the sample app on live and sandbox and do not see this issue.  I am investigating internally what may be going on here but, can you try this again today and see if the behavior is different?

Comment: @MattJacunski Yes I checked it again, having same issue still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bot - The merchant account (the one associated with the app client ID) cannot be the same one used as the buyer.  Looks like maybe that is the case here.

See https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/110

Try using a different account as the buyer.

Comment: I have one question that How can I refund this amount if I want, any way to do this from dashboard ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to see your REST API transaction from the dashboard at https://developer.paypal.com

Comment: I can see but there is nothing related to refund amount of any user, can you paste here any link to do this how ?